# Java Fx not working properly when using socket loop

Tags: java, sockets, javafx

i have some problem with java fx, i'm developing a Service Mail and i have a problem with showing server stage ( with java fx).
By using the pattern MVC i created:
1) MainServer.java ( where i start the java fx application)
2) ControllerServer.java ( Controller class)
3) ServerLog.java ( Model class, not important for my question, but had to mention it).

Now, i have another class called Server.java where there is the real server code, i tried to merge MainServer.java with Server.java by moving Server.java code into ControllerServer.java, server is working good, but stage does not show the stage, i think the problem is in while loop inside the initializable.

```
public class Server {
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    private static ServerLog serverLog = new ServerLog();

    public static void getService(Socket s) throws IOException {
         // not important for my question so deleted
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new File("users").mkdir();
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8189);

                while(true) {
                    Socket s = socket.accept();
                    getService(s);
                }

        }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
}
```

```
public class ServerMain extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View/server.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Server Log");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

```
public class ControllerServer implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ListView myListView;


    //protected List<String> listLog = new ArrayList<>();
    protected ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();
    private ServerLog serverLog = new ServerLog();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try {
            serverLog.fillLogList();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (serverLog.logList!= null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < serverLog.logList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(serverLog.logList.get(i));
            }
            ObservableList<String> seasonList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(serverLog.logList);
            myListView.setItems(seasonList);
        }

    }
}
```

what i want to do is delete ServerMain.java and transfer what ServerMain.java was doing into Server ( so server need to show the stage when opened)

Comment: You're probably blocking the _JavaFX Application Thread_ with that `while` loop, though I'm not sure since you have multiple `main` methods (entry points). If you are, move the server work onto a background thread—see [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: thanks for replying my question, yes you see multiple main, but when i tried to merge there was just one main method, i think the problem could be with initializable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

had to edit my answer because at the end it worked, but not properly, with this class now i can see java fx stage correctly but server stopped work correctly, so if anyone have a better solution i would be honored to read this solution :( .

```
public class Server extends Application {
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    private static ServerLog serverLog = new ServerLog();

    public static void getService(Socket s) throws IOException { ... }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
        new File("users").mkdir();
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8189);

                while(true) {
                    Socket s = socket.accept();
                    getService(s);
                }

        }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View/server.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Server Log");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application#launch` will block the calling thread until the JavaFX runtime exits. As you want to listen for connections in a loop, you _really_ need a background thread. Read the article I linked to in the question comments. If that doesn't help because you're brand new to multi-threading, I suggest reading [Lesson: Concurrency (The Java™ Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) as a start (concurrency is an advanced topic). Note, one place you can launch this background work is in your controller class, maybe using a `Service`.

Comment: i'm not that new in multi-threading but this is the first time somethign like that happened, thank you for links, i'm already reading background thread for a bit after looking for other similar questions in stack overflow and i'll use it because i don't see any other option :), thank you very much.

Comment: I created a background thread and it worked correctly, thank you!